# TypeORM Many-To-Many find where Relation is Null

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

im a little bit stuck atm as im trying to find empty relations.
my Relation looks like this (Postgres)

```
@Entity()
export class Permission {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Ticket, (ticket) => ticket.permissions, {
    nullable: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  tickets?: Ticket[];
}





@Entity()
export class Ticket {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToMany(() => Permission, (permission) => permission.tickets, {
    cascade: true,
    nullable: true,
  })
  @JoinTable()
  permissions?: Permission[];
```

my Query is looking like this

```
  const openTickets = await this.ticketRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('ticket')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('ticket.permissions', 'ticketPermission')
    .where('ticketPermission.id IN (:...myPermissions)', {
      myPermissions,
    })
    .getMany();
```

myPermissions is an array with the User permissions set and i get all tickets where my Permission is set but i dont know how to add tickets to the query that doesnt have any Permission set.
i tried to do something like `.where('ticketPermission.id IN (:...myPermissions) OR ticketPermission IS NULL',`
But it throws an error if i try to do this and ticketPermission.id IS NULL does nothing.

Comment: "myPermissions is an array with the User permissions set" -- what is the type of `myPermissions`?

Comment: myPermissions is an array of numbers.

Comment: What is the error it throws? What isn't working about the code you posted?

Comment: No Error, i Wanted to add to my query that it also gives me the tickets that doesnt have any permission set .

My solution now was to just make a second query and concat the results :/.

Comment: I wonder if you could use the `ON` of the left join? E.g. `.leftJoinAndSelect('ticket.permissions', 'ticketPermission', 'ticketPermission.id IN (:...myPermissions)')` (using `setParameter` to set the `myPermissions` parameter)